# How can I use Jupyter Notebook on macOS Catalina (without anaconda)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, macos-catalina

I've tried since yesterday to launch anaconda after I install the new version of macOS Catalina (before I understand that it is a beta version), and I finally find a way. But unfortunately, I can not launch Jupiter notebook from terminal because apparently it is not installed and it doesn't want to neither. How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 4):

I have also found some problems with the new Catalina update.
I believe this may be due to the terminal switching from bash to zsh.

However, I have been able to make Jupyter notebook work again by running (just double-click) the "**Update Shell Profile.command**" file located in the "Python 3.7" folder (found in the Applications folder).

Then run `jupyter notebook` on the terminal as usual.

Let me know if this helps!

PS: While you are at it you might also want to run the "Install Certificates.command" file.

Comment: I followed your recommandations, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. But at least, I thank you for the information of zsh/bash. Indeed, I didn't know about that. I tried to switch from zsh to bash with **exec bash** and then try the commande **jupyter notebook** but it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 4):

Try installing Jupyter with Homebrew, this method has worked for me.

Use the following command in Terminal:

`brew install jupyter`

Then launch a Jupyter notebook with:

`jupyter notebook`

This should also work for JupyterLab:

`jupyter lab`

And in case you don't have Homebrew installed, start with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: thank you! so simple :) this was the first method of many that worked for me

Comment: I'm glad it helped. And one more thing that might be useful here: if you use Jupyter Notebooks without Anaconda, the package management is a bit less straightforward. Here is an article that provides a really good explanation of how you can [install Python packages from a Jupyter Notebook](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/).

Comment: This is the best solution and worked on OS Catalina -- faced a lot of trouble in initiating notebook and lab when installed using pip, so uninstalled through pip and used this homebrew approach.

Answer (score 0):

Tried running (just double-click) the "Update Shell Profile.command" file but does not help. I still get the below error:

```
<my name>$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/<my name>/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/Users/<my name>/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .config_manager import BaseJSONConfigManager
  File "/Users/<my name>/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 14, in <module>
    from traitlets.config import LoggingConfigurable
  File "/Users/<my name>/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .traitlets import *
  File "/Users/<my name>/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 57, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```